# css3 animation possible to have callbacks?

Tags: animation, css, callback

I have been looking around to see css3 animations have some kind of callback, I.e is possible to animate an element, and once the element is finished animating, animate another?

Been bashing around google for hours to no avail, maybe my terminology is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 animations are not meant to replace JavaScript.

CSS is made *purely* for styling purposes with very minimal logic that does not "look back" (you cannot select a parent). CSS is handled on the spot and is triggered using a few browser triggers like `:hover`, `:active`, and `:link`.

CSS is supposed to be lightning fast, as it has no confusing or time-consuming logic that will slow down the browser.

That being said, callbacks aren't supported for the above reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Take a Look at Apple's talk "CSS Effects, Part 2: Galleries and 3D Effects from WWDC 2010":
https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/

You can provide a startdelay for your animation and there is some kind of transitionEndListener for webkit-based browser.